# Qt is it possible to define a function pointer in place of a signal?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I have a lot of signals which all have the same parameters but perform different functions.

The connect and disconnect code for all the signals will be the same, as is the slot handler that the signals connect to.

Instead of writing this code over and over. I would like to use a function pointer or something similar to assign to the signal, then have a common code block which performs the connection or disconnection.

The following code is just to illustrate what I am describing, it isn't valid and will not compile.

```
    void (*pfnSignal)(quint8, QString);
    switch( eSigID ) {
    case SIGNAL_A:
        pfnSignal = signalA; 
        break;
    case SIGNAL_B:
        pfnSignal = signalB;
        break;
    default:
        pfnSignal = NULL;           
    }
    if ( pfnSignal != NULL ) {
      QObject::connect(pobjRef, pfnSignal, this, SLOT(handler(quint8, QString)));
    }
```

Comment: Does the `handler` use `QObject::sender`? If not, what's the functionality of the signals if they are all handled by the same slot? Is the slot some sort of monitor/supervisor?

Comment: My application has lots of different signals and slots, this was just to manage a number of signals that are addressed to the same slot.

Comment: What about `sender()` - do you use that method (you shouldn't, so I'm just making sure you don't)?

Comment: No I don't, I just use QObject::connect and QObject::disconnect and emit to sent the signal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Qt5, this can be done easily, as it allows connecting using a [new pointer to member function syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

```
// Using decltype to avoid figuring out the ugly pointer-to-member-function syntax. 
// Assumes all signals have the same arguments.    
decltype<&ThatClass::someSignal> pfnSignal = nullptr;
switch( eSigID ) {
case SIGNAL_A:
    pfnSignal = &ThatClass::signalA; 
    break;
case SIGNAL_B:
    pfnSignal = &ThatClass::signalB;
    break;          
}

if (pfnSignal) {
    connect(pobjRef, pfnSignal, this, &ThisClass::handler);
}
```

But actually, this is even possible with Qt4, as the `SIGNAL` macro is of type `const char*`.

```
const char *pfnSignal = nullptr;
switch( eSigID ) {
case SIGNAL_A:
    pfnSignal = SIGNAL(signalA(quint8, QString)); 
    break;
case SIGNAL_B:
    pfnSignal = SIGNAL(signalB(quint8, QString)); 
    break;         
}
if (pfnSignal) {
  QObject::connect(pobjRef, pfnSignal, this, SLOT(handler(quint8, QString)));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

C++11 allows you to write very concise Qt code.

1. Leverage [range-based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to iterate over pointers. Those can be pointers to widgets, pointers to methods, etc:

   ```
   for (auto signal : {&Class::signal1, &Class:signal2})
      QObject::connect(sender, signal, receiver, slot);
   ```
2. Leverage [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to capture constant argument values:

   ```
   auto const cMySlot = [&](void (Sender::*signal)(int)){
     QObject::connect(sender, signal, receiver, slot);
   ```

Then:

```
for (auto signal : {&Class::signal1, &Class:signal2}) cMySlot(signal);
```

Full example:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/signals-simpler-43631464
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <initializer_list>

class Receiver : public QLabel {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Receiver(QWidget * parent = {}) : QLabel{parent} {}
   Q_SLOT void intSlot(int val) {
      setText(QStringLiteral("int = %1").arg(val));
   }
};

class Sender : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   QFormLayout m_layout{this};
   QPushButton btn1{"Send 1"}, btn2{"Send 5"}, btn3{"Send 10"};
public:
   Sender(QWidget * parent = {}) : QWidget{parent} {
      m_layout.setMargin(1);
      for (auto w : {&btn1, &btn2, &btn3}) m_layout.addWidget(w);
      auto const clicked = &QPushButton::clicked;
      connect(&btn1, clicked, this, [this]{ emit signal1(1); });
      connect(&btn2, clicked, this, [this]{ emit signal2(5); });
      connect(&btn3, clicked, this, [this]{ emit signal3(10); });
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void signal1(int);
   Q_SIGNAL void signal2(int);
   Q_SIGNAL void signal3(int);
};

using Widgets = std::initializer_list<QWidget*>;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QWidget win;
   QVBoxLayout layout{&win};
   Sender sender;
   Receiver receiver;
   for (auto w : Widgets{&sender, &receiver}) layout.addWidget(w);

   // Factor out connection
   auto const cIntSlot = [&](void (Sender::*signal)(int)){
      QObject::connect(&sender, signal, &receiver, &Receiver::intSlot);
   };
   // Factor out connection on a list
   for (auto signal : {&Sender::signal1, &Sender::signal2, &Sender::signal3})
      cIntSlot(signal);

   win.show();
   return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: My application generates a GUI entirely from an XML file, the signals and slots are used to mange subscriptions between GUI controls and the core application, it all works really well.

Comment: How you generate the GUI doesn't change any of it. All I'm demonstrating is that the `SIGNAL_A` enum abstraction that you're proposing is not useful at all. Use `&Class::signalA` instead and you're set. It's a first-class C++ value. You could also make the GUI act as a view for a `QAbstractTableModel` representing the data in the application, and then the "subscriptions" would be entirely automatic. You could use `QDataWidgetMapper` for the mappings, or roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Thomas McGuire was faster than me. (Damn.) Though, I want to add this answer because:

1. It provides a complete sample.
2. It uses functors instead of object/member function pointers for signal handlers.

Thus, it may be and add-on to the answer of Thomas McGuire.

Before Qt 5 the signal was described by a `char*` which should be very simple to handle. Therefore, I assume your question is concerning the new API since Qt 5.

This should work as well if you use the correct method pointer type. I did this for [`QPushButton`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QPushButton.html) and [`QCheckBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QCheckBox.html) for demonstration because both are derived from [`QAbstractButton`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QAbstractButton.html) which in turn has two signals with equal signature. IMHO equal signature of signals is mandatory for your solution.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

enum SigType { None, Click, Toggle };

template <typename FUNCTOR>
void installSignalHandler(
  QAbstractButton *pQBtn,
  SigType sigType,
  FUNCTOR sigSlot)
{
  void (QAbstractButton::*pSignal)(bool) = nullptr;
  switch (sigType) {
    case Click: pSignal = &QAbstractButton::clicked; break;
    case Toggle: pSignal = &QAbstractButton::toggled; break;
  }
  if (pSignal) QObject::connect(pQBtn, pSignal, sigSlot);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version: " << QT_VERSION_STR;
  // main application
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWin;
  QVBoxLayout qVBox(&qWin);
  QPushButton qBtn1("Button 1 -> Click");
  qVBox.addWidget(&qBtn1);
  QPushButton qBtn2("Button 2 -> Toggle");
  qVBox.addWidget(&qBtn2);
  QPushButton qBtn3("Button 3 -> None");
  qVBox.addWidget(&qBtn3);
  QCheckBox qTgl1("Toggle 1 -> Click");
  qVBox.addWidget(&qTgl1);
  QCheckBox qTgl2("Toggle 2 -> Toggle");
  qVBox.addWidget(&qTgl2);
  QCheckBox qTgl3("Toggle 3 -> None");
  qVBox.addWidget(&qTgl3);
  qWin.show();
  // install signal handlers
  installSignalHandler(&qBtn1, Click,
    [](bool) { qDebug() << "Button 1 received clicked."; });
  installSignalHandler(&qBtn2, Toggle,
    [](bool) { qDebug() << "Button 2 received toggled."; });
  installSignalHandler(&qBtn3, None, // will be actually never called
    [](bool) { qDebug() << "Button 3 received none."; });
  installSignalHandler(&qTgl1, Click,
    [](bool) { qDebug() << "CheckBox 1 received clicked."; });
  installSignalHandler(&qTgl2, Toggle,
    [](bool) { qDebug() << "CheckBox 2 received toggled."; });
  installSignalHandler(&qTgl2, None, // will be actually never called
    [](bool) { qDebug() << "CheckBox 3 received none."; });
  // run-time loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Compiled and tested with VisualStudio & Qt 5.6 on Windows 10 (64 bit):

[image: Snapshot of running sample]

Comment: 1. The `qFoo` global symbol space is reserved for Qt. You'll be fighting it to no end - don't use such names. 2. Don't use a `QMainWindow` when a `QWidget` will do. Other than that, just FYI as this is a great answer: If you wish, you could make the test case shorter: 3. `QLayout layout(&widget)` will save a line as you don't need `setLayout`. 4. Use `qDebug() << "foo"` or `plainTextEdit.appendPlainText("foo")` instead of iostreams. 5. `#include <QtWidgets>` instead of individual includes.

Comment: @KubaOber IMHO your critical statements address matters of taste. However, because I'm still feeling new in Qt (switched from gtkmm just last year) it can't hurt to consider the one who are an old hand... -> sample code improved according to your comments.